# get notified on connection state change with IWD

Tags: linux, callback, wifi

I wrote a systray area applet that displays the status of IWD backed WiFi connection. Right now my app polls `iwctl station wlp4s0 show` every minute and parses the result. Is there a way to avoid polling and use some sort of a notification hook?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to do this with linux netlink protocol.

```bash
man 7 netlink
```

```bash
apt get install libnl-3-dev  libnl-genl-3-dev
```

Basically:

```c
int fd = socket(PF_NETLINK, SOCK_RAW, NETLINK_ROUTE);
struct sockaddr_nl snl = { .... };
bind(fd, &snl, sizeof(snl));
while (1) {
   recv(fd, buf, sizeof(buf), 0);
   struct nlmsghdr *nlh = (struct nlmsghdr *)buf;
   ...
}
```

`recv` will block until events related to network interfaces happen, then data you need is in `nlh`.

For example check for new connection:

```c
if (nlh->nlmsg_type == RTM_NEWADDR) ...
```